# Prolog unique value in list

Tags: prolog

I learing Prolog language for exam at college and I don't know how to create function which: check unique values in list. I mean, if each value in list are unique function return true, otherwise return false. eg.

```
[1,2,3,5] - true
[1,2,2,4] - false
```

Header for this function is uniqueValues(X) X - mean list. I really don't know this language and if anyone can explain me how to create this function will be great. Thanks in advence for help

Comment: sorry my bad, changed.

Comment: Check this post out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426484/how-to-find-differences-in-lists-in-prolog-and-determine-if-the-lists-are-the-sa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not knowing Prolog, this is going to be a bit of a haul, but let's give it a shot. In Prolog, functions work by *recursion* rather than iteration. For list processing, this means (in general) you have to decide how to handle the empty list and how to handle an element in front of some other list. So first, you need to make a decision about the empty list.

```
unique([]).
```

This says "empty lists are unique." This is a helpful property.

The recursive case assumes that you already know how to handle the rest of the list. In "ordinary" recursive list processing predicates like this, you tend to have this kind of structure:

```
foo([X|Xs]) :- /* do something with X */, foo(Xs).
```

The `foo(Xs)` there is saying, "and run this same thing on whatever's left." So the question we have to ask is, how do we know if a list that starts with X and ends with Xs is unique? Well, we can make sure that X is unique my ensuring it doesn't occur else where in the list. Like this:

```
unique([X|Xs]) :- \+ memberchk(X, Xs).
```

Consider your example `[1,2,3,4]`. The first time in, X = 1 and Xs = [2,3,4]. `\+` means "not" in Prolog, and `memberchk/2` tells you whether something is in a list. So `memberchk(1, [2,3,4])` will fail and the `\+` will turn that failure into success. This is good! Also, with `[1,2,1]`, X will equal 1 and Xs will equal [2,1], the `memberchk/2` will succeed, and then be negated into a failure. This is probably what we want!

Putting that together with the recursive call, you get this for the entire predicate:

```
unique([]).
unique([X|Xs]) :- \+ memberchk(X, Xs), unique(Xs).
```

1. Empty lists are unique.
2. Lists that are not empty ([X|Xs]) are unique if:

   1. Xs does not contain X, and
   2. Xs is also unique

Comment: `\+ memberchk(X, Xs)` -> `\+ member(X, Xs)`

Comment: @PauloMoura why would I prefer member in this case?

Comment: Successful calls to `\+/1` do not return bindings and do not allow backtracking into its argument ...

Comment: @PauloMoura I don't bindings or backtracking for this task. I don't see what I'd be buying by changing it.

Comment: The difference between the definitions of `memberchk/2` and `member/2` is a cut in the former. That cut is useless in this case.

Comment: @PauloMoura I tend to use `memberchk/2` whenever I don't need backtracking or unification, and this is one of those cases. I don't think it matters which one is used here. But you're more experienced than me, so if you know a concrete difference, a reason I should use it, I would.

Comment: If the element is present in the list, the cut in the `memberchk/2` definition is useless as the call will succeed making the call to `\+/1` fail. But the same is true if you use instead `member/2`. If the element is not present, both `memberchk/2` and `member/2` will traverse the whole list and fail, making the call to `\+/1` succeed. In both cases, there will be no bindings returned or any backtracking to the `\+/1` call.

Comment: @PauloMoura Right... so I don't see the point to changing it.

Comment: I think you're being needlessly fussy, but for the edification of other programmers, you should make your commentary into an answer.